# nsdate from string works only with date not time

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

im using a string to convert it to an nsDate

is working fine,
but when i try to add time to my string I get null on the logs

```
NSString *dateStringus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12-09-2011"];
NSLog(@"%@",dateStringus);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormattero = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormattero setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSDate* d = [dateFormattero dateFromString:dateStringus];
NSLog(@"tomad tu string date ::%@",d);    

NSString *pingus = [dateFormattero stringFromDate:d];

NSLog(@"transumatada ::%@", pingus);

NSLog(@"\n");
```

Works fine for only date,
but

if I do

```
NSString *dateStringus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12-09-2011 14:14:00"];
```

I get null on the logs

how to fix this string to include time? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dateFormat` property of the `NSDateFormatter` `dateFormattero` must match the format of date/time in the string `dateStringus`.

Change:

```
[dateFormattero setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
```

Into:

```
[dateFormattero setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

Here is a good [reference](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns) on date format patterns.